# Redirect Json data to another view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a form where the user submit a code, after this I have a function that receive this code as parameter and make a consult on an API. The API returns a JSON data. And I would like to show this data that I received on a new page. How can I pass this JSON data to another view and render it?

Here is my class and `json_data` contains my json response

```
class IndexPageView(FormView):

template_name = 'home.html'
form_class = StudentVerificationForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('core:home')

def form_valid(self, form):
    student_enrollment_number = form.cleaned_data['enrollment_number']
    json_data = student_exists(student_enrollment_number)

    return redirect('some-view')
```

Comment: What does json_data consist of? Is it some large dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would recommend using [Django Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/)

Any view will be able to get the data with this.

Answer (score 0):

Following Django Session concepts I solved it this way:

```
class IndexPageView(FormView):

template_name = 'home.html'
form_class = StudentVerificationForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('core:home')

def form_valid(self, form):
    student_enrollment_number = form.cleaned_data['enrollment_number']
    # store the variable on django session 
    self.request.session['enrollment_number'] = student_enrollment_number 

    return redirect('confirm')
```

After this I created another view and retrieve the value from the session

```
def confirm(request):

student_enrollment_number = request.session['enrollment_number']
...
```

From here I can do data processing that I want to do

Comment: Note Bene: it's good of you to post your code to help others, but please in the future give the accepted answer check to those who provided the solution you used.